# Passing Argument x ... from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, makefile

I'm getting a compiler error when trying to pass the address of an integer over to a function to be received as a pointer. This used to be working, but then I made some changes in my Makefile and now it doesn't work any longer. I doubt if it's syntax, but here it is:

helper_funcs.h

```
void make_passive_connections(int *sockfd, Neighbor *neighbor, FILE *logfd, char this_router[64], struct sockaddr_in servAddr);
```

helper_funcs.c

```
void make_passive_connections(int *sockfd, Neighbor *neighbor, FILE *logfd, char this_router[64], struct sockaddr_in servAddr) {
    ...
}
```

in the calling program

```
    int sockfd;
    ...
    make_passive_connections(&sockfd, &neighbor, logfd, this_router->label, &servAddr, &num_hosts);
    ...
}
```

The compiler also tells me that I am passing too many arguments. Is my computer having a bad day or what I am I overlooking?

Here is my Makefile if it helps:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall -Wextra
SOURCES = fork.c helper_funcs.c primary.c
DEPS = primary.h fork.h helper_funcs.h
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE = primary

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

#.c.o:
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)
```

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘make_passive_connections’ from
>   incompatible pointer type

EDIT: I'm an idiot. I forgot to delete the last argument in my function call. But my main issue is why the compiler thinks that passing the address of an integer to a function that expects a pointer to an integer isn't working. Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: Well, you are passing 1 argument too much. What is the error you are getting exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It's your syntax, I've lined things up differently:

declaration:

```
void make_passive_connections(int *sockfd,    Neighbor *neighbor,
                              FILE *logfd,    char this_router[64],
                              struct sockaddr_in servAddr);
```

call

```
make_passive_connections(     &sockfd,        &neighbor,
                              logfd,          this_router->label,
                              &servAddr,      &num_hosts);
```

As you can see, you are passing six parameters where five are expected. I'm having as bad a day as your compiler. You are also passing an address of a struct (I assume) where a struct (by value) is expected.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted in the earlier line of code. You're right about that. I'm still getting the error about incompatible pointer types on argument 1. I'm passing the address of an integer and the function expects a pointer to an integer. I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: @usr55410: Without a complete compilable example it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype:

```
void make_passive_connections(int *sockfd, Neighbor *neighbor, FILE *logfd, char this_router[64], struct sockaddr_in servAddr);
```

Is calling for one less argument (5) then you have passed (6):

```
make_passive_connections(&sockfd, &neighbor, logfd, this_router->label, &servAddr, &num_hosts);
```

and where the 5th argument is asking for `struct sockaddr_in`, you are passing a `char *`, `this_router->label`.

Change your call to:  (delete last argument, and pass only `this_router`)

```
 make_passive_connections(&sockfd, &neighbor, logfd, this_router, &servAddr);
```